# lua - dofile, how fill stdin from lua?

Tags: lua

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-dofile tells

```
dofile ([filename])
```

Opens the named file and executes its contents as a Lua chunk. When called without arguments, dofile executes the contents of the standard input (stdin). Returns all values returned by the chunk. In case of errors, dofile propagates the error to its caller (that is, dofile does not run in protected mode).

How fill stdin from lua for case when called without arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running a lua script or the lua interpreter in interactive mode from a command shell, calling `dofile()` will just get input from stdin. You'll see a blinking cursor in the shell where you can enter the lua code you want to run.

Note, running `dofile` in this fashion is a *blocking* calling, which means execution flow in your script or the lua interpreter will pause until it reads eof. Usually this means you have to enter <kbd>Ctrl + Z</kbd> under windows or <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd> under *nix bash shell at the end.

Comment: is here any symbols representing EOF to end typing so i can type any code and that symbol instead of ctrl-z or ctrl-D?

or maybe here is some way to pass raw code as argument to dofile?

Comment: hitting `ctrl + z`should input eof. Just hit `enter` afterwards. If you're on a posix environment use `ctrl + d` instead.

Comment: ctrl-z can't be used in my case, because commands sent with client chat to server, when i remotely run dofile without args, server main loop seems to pause and server can't read any clients commands anymore or do anything else :(

Comment: Have you tried using `loadstring` instead and passing the code you want to run?

Comment: yeah, but due limitations of host program i can't use idiom loadstring("code")(), only loadstring("code") and can't return it's result to any variable

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
-bash-4.0$ ./lua
Lua 5.3.0 (alpha)  Copyright (C) 1994-2014 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> dofile()
a = 3; print(a)
3
>
```

After inputting `a = 3; print(a)`, I pressed <kbd>Ctrl + D</kbd>, which represents `EOF` on Unix. `dofile()` loads the input and executes it.